# Create An Array Dynamically, Then Loop Through Another Array To Compare If Data Exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops

What I am trying to achieve is to create an array dynamically and then use that array to compare with another array if data exist.

What is happening right now is that the code to compare the arrays is executing before the array is finish creating. Essentially I am comparing my data to an empty array.

What technique can I use to make the code execute `code a` completely then when `code a` is finished execute `code b`?

```
var awayTeamPlayersPlayedArray = [];
vm.awayTeamPlayers = $firebaseArray(awayTeamPlayersQuery);

// add data to awayTeamPlayersPlayedArray
angular.forEach(vm.awayTeamPlayersPlayed, function(value, key) {
    var awayTeamPlayerRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'players/' + key);
    var awayTeamPlayer = $firebaseObject(awayTeamPlayerRef);
    awayTeamPlayer.$loaded().then(function() {
        awayTeamPlayersPlayedArray.push(awayTeamPlayer.name);
        console.log(awayTeamPlayersPlayedArray)
    });
});

// loop through vm.awayTeamPlayers to see if they exist in awayTeamPlayersPlayedArray
angular.forEach(vm.awayTeamPlayers, function(value, key) {
    if(awayTeamPlayersPlayedArray.indexOf(value.name) > -1) {
        console.log(value.name + ' yes');
    } else {
        console.log(value.name + ' no');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use loop after all Promises will be finished.

```
var allPromises = [];
// add data to awayTeamPlayersPlayedArray
angular.forEach(vm.awayTeamPlayersPlayed, function(value, key) {
  var awayTeamPlayerRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'players/' + key);
  var awayTeamPlayer = $firebaseObject(awayTeamPlayerRef);
  var promise = awayTeamPlayer.$loaded().then(function() {
    awayTeamPlayersPlayedArray.push(awayTeamPlayer.name);
    console.log(awayTeamPlayersPlayedArray);
  });
  allPromises.push(promise);
});
$q.all(allPromises).then(function() {
  // loop through vm.awayTeamPlayers to see if they exist in awayTeamPlayersPlayedArray

  angular.forEach(vm.awayTeamPlayers, function(value, key) {
    if(awayTeamPlayersPlayedArray.indexOf(value.name) > -1) {
      console.log(value.name + ' yes');
    } else {
      console.log(value.name + ' no');
    }
  });
});
```